# Delete 2nd and 3rd occurrence of an element

Tags: prolog

I want to make a program that given a list L in which element X appears 3 times, it returns the NL list including it only one time.
For example, this question

```
?- erase([1,2,3,1,6,1,7],1,NL).
```

should return

```
NL = [1,2,3,6,7]  or  NL = [2,3,1,6,7]  or  NL = [2,3,6,1,7]
```

P.S. 
Suppose that the given list doesn't include any element 2,4 or more times.
So, this is my code, but it returns false when I make a question. Any suggestion to correct it would be appreciated.

```
erase([],_,[]).
erase(L,X,NL):-
                append(A,[X,B,X,C,X,D],L),
                append(A,[X,B,C,D],NL).
```

Comment: What if it occurs four times? Whould we only look for `1`? Or remove *all* elements that occur multiple times?

Comment: As i 've written in the P.S suppose that this case won't exist

Comment: I would start with *duck debugging*: tell (to your rubber duck, or to us) what your predicate aims to do. Why do you use `append/3` here? Why do you think this is the good tool for this problem?

Comment: Yes what you say is the classic tactic but i thought that append could do the work and even with less lines. Do you agree?

Comment: it would only work on certain patterns of lists. Here `B` in your list is a *single* element. So that means that your list `[1,2,3,1,6,1,7]` can not be processed, since there are two elements between the first and second 1: `2` and `3`.

Comment: That's true, my code isn't general.Thank you, I will try your perspective.

Answer (score 4):

So you say, that the following query should succeed, but fails

```
?- erase([1,2,3,1,6,1,7],1,NL).
   false.
```

even the following generalization fails:

```
?- erase([1,2,3,1,6,1,7],E,NL).
   false.
```

Let me reformulate this for easier access:

```
?- L = [1,2,3,1,6,1,7], erase(L,E,NL).
   false.
```

So we now have to generalize that list even further. I could try this element by element, but I rather prefer first:

```
?- L = [_,_,_,_,_,_,_], erase(L,E,NL).
   L = [_A,E,_B,E,_C,E,_D], NL = [_A,E,_B,_C,_D]
;  false.
```

This is the only answer. It tells us that `E` has to occur exactly at the 2nd, 3rd and 5th position. Let's try if that is true:

```
?- erase([0,1,0,1,0,1,0],1,NL).
   NL = [0,1,0,0,0]
;  false.
```

So your solution works — sometimes. It seems that you rather want:

```
erase(L, X, NL) :-
   phrase(
      ( seq(Any1), [X], seq(Any2), [X], seq(Any3), [X], seq(Any4) ), L),
   phrase(
      ( seq(Any1),      seq(Any2),      seq(Any3), [X], seq(Any4) ), NL).

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).
```

Comment: Nice point here, it should work wherever the X element may be positioned. Your suggestion luckily works, but could you make mine work too? I mean with the append/3. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @kindaExcited: That's very complex: you need at least 6 (six) `append/3` goals

Comment: Oh, I reject it immediatly then.

Answer (score 0):

append/2 helps a lot when processing multiple lists:

```
erase(L,E,R) :-
    append([A,[E],B,[E],C,[E],D],L),
    select([E],[X,Y,Z],[[],[]]),
    append([A, X, B, Y, C, Z, D],R).
```